# Php variable obj to js

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, object

I am using codeigniter. Here is my php code to query result in array of obj then how can i pass them to js. I wanna use it in google maps

```
    <?php
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $lat = $row->geo_lat;
        $lng = $row->geo_lng;
        $pic = $row->picture;
        echo $lat;
        echo $lng;
        echo "<img src=\"" . base_url() . $pic . "\"/><br />";
        //echo json_encode($row);
        //echo "<pre>";
        //echo print_r($row);
    }
?>
```

Js code

```
var locations = ?????????;
var marker, i;
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
      map: map,
      draggable: true
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can emit Javascript with PHP...why don't you just JSON-encode all of the results and store them in your `locations` variable, like so:

```
<?php 
    echo( "<script>" );
    echo( "  var locations = " + json_encode($query->result()) + ";" );
    echo( "</script>" );
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use it with or without ajax.

You can simply have overall `result` in json format using json_encode() _and add it to js variable like:

```
<script>
    var js_obj=<?php echo  json_encode($result); ?>
  /* now you can access this json object that is in js_obj variable and acccess any thing you want using dot operator.*/
</script>
```

Your question is not much clear so if you are asking in some different sense then please be clear so that I can focus on actual problem.

Comment: You codes is working to me. But if i change to this, it doesn't work.
In my codeigniter controller.

$json = json_encode($data['query']->result());

then in my external js file. I use jquery .ajax to access it
alert(json[0].foo);

Comment: @vzhen if you want to use it via ajax then from PHP echo it and then access from your .ajax

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *AJAX* to have your JS code to ask for the PHP page. The PHP page will process the request, and return appropriate data in JSON format (using `json_encode()` on the result object).